# Changing <p> with a dropped href

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem: I have PHP code that generates objects from my database that looks like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) 
            {
    list($news_id, $news_name, $news_img, $news_date, $news_link) = $result->fetch_row(); 

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$news_date.'</td>';
    echo '<td id="udrag'.$i.'"><a href="get_news.php?newsid='.$news_id.'" id="drag'.$news_id.'" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">'.$news_name.'</a></td>';
    echo '<td><img src="'.$news_img.'" style="width:50px" /></td>';
    echo '<td>'.$string1 = substr($news_link, 0, strpos($news_link, 'com')+2).'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    }
```

It gets all news from my database, puts them into table and adds an href link which you can click to see the news. As you can see it also is draggable.

I want to drag one of those links into a

with an ondrop event, like this:

```
 <div id="boxUp"><p id="a1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">main news</p></div>
```

After the drop is complete, i want to put inside the paragraph dragged a href element so it looks like this:

```
 <div id="boxUp"><p id="a1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><a href="get_news.php?newsid=5" id="drag5" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">some news name</a></p></div>
```

I can't figure out what I need to do in order to get this effect, my code is as follows. Any help?

```
function allowDrop(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) 
{
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
    var elo = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");  
}
function drop(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    //ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));     
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lzy5v/8/

Comment: adding a link to a jsfiddle will help us help you

Comment: added a link to jsfiddle

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I see none.

Comment: @j08691 sorry it was an irrelevant part of the code, deleted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used ev.dataTransfer.getData('text') on the drag event right after using setData, it seems you can only do that on the drop event otherwise the drop event won't even get fired, delete your "var elo = ...." and uncomment the last line of your drop function and all done, i modified your jsfiddle so you can check:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lzy5v/11/

```
    <div id="boxUp">
    <p id="a1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        Place to drag the news and change this p into the news after drop
    </p>
</div>

<a href="get_news.php?newsid=397" id="link" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">some news</a>

<script>
    function allowDrop(ev)  {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev)   {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev)   {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text"); 
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));       
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, but now my link is getting copied, what i want is for the link to replace the P text, any idea how to do that ?

Comment: If you don't want to create a copy of the link you must remove the "cloneNode(true)" method, i left it there because you didn't specify that. Now if you want to replace the text in your <p> tag you can do several things, just replace it by setting it's innerHTML to an empty string, but anytime you drop another link inside that <p> tag will remove any previously droped link too, so i don't recommend that, you could also put the instructions outside that <p> tag, lets say on an h4, and you could hide that after the first drop by setting its display property to none http://jsfiddle.net/Lzy5v/12/